# Second of several forked processes does not run in Haskell (GHC 7.8.4)

Tags: perl, haskell, io

I have a simple Haskell program that forks off several processes, each of which sleeps for a certain number of seconds and then echos. Regardless of how many processes I fork, the second one does not seem to output any visible content to the terminal.

```
import System.Process (createProcess, proc, shell, CreateProcess)
import Text.Printf (printf, PrintfArg)
import Control.Concurrent (forkIO)
import Control.Monad (void)

sleep :: Integer -> CreateProcess
sleep x = shell (printf "sleep %d; echo %d" x x)
-- sleep x = shell (printf "sleep %d, echo %d, touch %d.haskell" x x x)

main = foldr1 (>>) $ [
  forkIO $ void $ createProcess task |
  task <- [ sleep 1, sleep 2, sleep 3, sleep 4, sleep 5] ]
```

produces

```
./scheduler 
user@name-of-computer $ 1
3
4
5
```

And if you run it with the commented line instead of just printing, you can see

```
$ 1.haskell  4.haskell
3.haskell  5.haskell
```

This behavior also seems to be specific to Haskell. Perl does not exhibit it.

```
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';

sub sleep_echo {
  my ($second_count) = @_;
  my $cpid = fork;
  if ($cpid == 0) {
    exec "sleep $second_count; echo $second_count";
  }
}

for (my $i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
  sleep_echo($i);
}
```

prints

```
user@name-of-computer $ 1
2
3
4
5
```

Any ideas as to what's going on?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, the code executes as expected on my machine. How exactly are you compiling and running it? Also, make your program print out each process ID and wait on each process.. Does it work if you hard code 2 processes? `forkIO (sleep 1) >> forkIO (sleep 2)`

Comment: @user2407038 I am running GHC version 7.8.4 on (X)Ubuntu 15.04. What are you using?

Comment: Unrelated to the actual issue: in Haskell you can also use one of `sequence`, `mapM`, `forM` or their `..._` variants instead of `foldr1 (>>) [...]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been able to reproduce this with GHC 7.10.2.

The Haskell and Perl versions are not strictly equivalent. The Perl version will create process after process, waiting the previous one to be launched (not finished).

The Haskell version will create several threads, each one launching one process.

Since you do not wait for your threads to finish launching their process, some threads will fail because your program ends too quickly. Thread execution in the Haskell runtime is not random, therefore your program will (generally) exhibit the same behavior again and again on your machine.

You can also try to increase the number of processes to see what happens. With 14 processes, the 13th process is not launched (on my configuration).

If you remove the `forkIO` call, your program will work just fine:

```
import System.Process (createProcess, proc, shell, CreateProcess)
import Text.Printf (printf, PrintfArg)
import Control.Monad (void)

sleep :: Integer -> CreateProcess
sleep x = shell (printf "sleep %d; echo %d" x x)

main = foldr1 (>>)
              [ void $ createProcess task
              | task <- fmap sleep [1..5]
              ]
```

Comment: So if the presence of active threads isn't sufficient to prevent the program from exiting, what is the condition?

I take it if I wanted to use threads, I would have to keep track of their `id`s and add an explicit wait.

Comment: Depending on what you’re doing, you can use `threadDelay` to wait 0.5 seconds at the end of your program (dirty) assuming the threads creation is very fast. Or you can follow the Terminating The Program section on https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html

Comment: @GregoryNisbet IIRC, as soon as the main thread exits, the other ones are terminated. Adding explicit waits would prevent that.